# $Resource error - when using $save.success callback but data is saving OK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources

I'm trying to use a resource to save some data, and am getting something strange happen:

here is the code:

```
var appointment = new Appointment(formData);
                    console.log(appointment);
                    appointment.$save().success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                         console.log(data);
                         $state.transitionTo('form.success');
                });
```

now the wierd thing is that the data is saving so the $save function is working, but I'm getting undefined is not a function errors, and the success callback isnt working - does anyone know why?

The resource for the Appointments is:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/admin/:id', { id: "@_id" }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });

})
```

and I'm using this and its inherent $save function, so it shouldn't be a problem - also it seems to be the callback thats not working - the save is adding data no problem

SOLUTION:

I simplified it by just doing:

```
appointment.$save(function(data){
//stuff here for the callback works
});
```

also I think that using the promise method .then would work, but I didn't try it.

I marked it as accepted anyway for good karma!

Thanks

Comment: the above is the whole function - unless you mean the Node part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `success` function is specific to the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service:

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

The `$save` method returns a regular promise, so you can use `then` instead:

```
appointment.$save().then(function (data, status, headers, config){
                     console.log(data);
                     $state.transitionTo('form.success');
            });
```